# If one object is touched by another object, do something?

Tags: object, vb6, collision-detection

I am making a game in which you move the character with the arrow keys, and I want to do something when it collides with a certain step. (See picture below). I want the top value of my character to increase every time it touches the steps, and the second flight of stairs, I want it to descend. I have tried and tried to no avail. Any help?

[image: Program Game]

Comment: And you haven't shown a single line of code. _Amazing_

Comment: The picture is pretty though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a [Bing search on Collosion detection with VB6](http://www.bing.com/search?q=collision%20detection%20algorithm%20vb6&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBLH), I found a few articles out there.

Try looking at:

- http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/rectangular-and-circular-collision-detection-vb6

But as @Matt Ball is trying to say, is in order to help you we need to see what code you have tried. Otherwise anything we come up with is just a guess of what your problem is.